# Previous page on MongoDB range query pagination

Tags: mongodb, pagination

I have a collection with articles. Because the collection is very big I have to use range queries for pagination (instead of the skip method).
In order to take the first page (of the most recent articles) using a range query on _id its straight forward:

```
db.articles.find({}, {title:1}).limit(10).sort({_id:-1})
```

In order to take the next page again is straightforward:

```
db.articles.find({"_id":{"$lt":ObjectId("43...75")}}, {title:1}).limit(10).sort({_id:-1})
```

(where the ObjectId is the _id of the last article of the current page)

And here comes the question: "How do i get the **PREVIOUS** page???"

My first thought was to use the same query using $gt instead of $lt and the _id of the first article of the current page. This however is wrong because if the current page has articles 50-60 the previous page will be 1-10.
In order to overcome this shortcoming, i could sort with sort({_id:1}) and reverse the results array, but i feel it like a hack...

Am I missing something obvious??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To paginate with a sort, you remember the highest entry of the previous page in order to return the next 10 results. For example, to paginate on the following collection

```
> for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) db.page.insert({ "x" : i })
```

you do the following

```
> var page = db.page.find().sort({ "x" : 1 }).limit(10)
// do stuff with the page and get the highest `x`
> var max_x = page.toArray()[9].x
> var next_page = db.page.find({ "x" : { "$gt" : max_x } }).sort({ "x" : 1 }).limit(10)
```

so there's a mapping `max_x` => `page`, i.e. given a `max_x` you can get the right page since `max_x` tells you the smallest value of `x` not on the page. So just remember the previous page's `max_x` (lower limit of the `x` for the docs on the page) and you can recall the page.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply. If I understood your solution, you are suggesting to remember a value from from the previous page (in users session for example). But what if someone follows a link to the third page (not passing from the first 2 pages)? I think, he can go only to the next page.

Comment: How did you construct the link to the third page without passing through the first two in that case?

Comment: If I pass the object id to the URL then the query will fetch me articles with object ids greater than the provided.

Comment: So fetch articles with object ids less than the one provided :D

Comment: So you are suggesting to use the solution that i describe in the end of my question?

Comment: Yup. The whole point of my answer is to help you understand how pagination works so that you can see going back in pages is the same thing as going forward. Don't forget you can reverse the order of sorts too: -1 instead of +1. This is free for non-compound indexes.

Comment: @wdberkeley to be clear. If i wanted to go from page 10 to page 9. I'd do `db.page.find({ "x" : { "$lt" : firstArrayItem } }).sort({ "x" : 1 }).limit(10)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it this way. Please comment if you have any better solution.

```
// import ObjectId from mongodb
let sortOrder = -1;
let query = []
if (prev) {
    sortOrder = 1
    query.push({title: 'findTitle', _id:{$gt: ObjectId('_idValue')}})
}

if (next) {
    sortOrder = -1
    query.push({title: 'findTitle', _id:{$lt: ObjectId('_idValue')}})
}

db.collection.find(query).limit(10).sort({_id: sortOrder})
```

Comment: Your answer will be more helpful to others if you explain why you chose this approach and what its advantages are over the other, accepted solution.